# Uploading multiple images within a json call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to modify a jquery script I use often in my  websites to integrate image uploads within it. Maybe it's a script that cannot be modified for this purpose otherwise I could do with some help. I dont really understand the 64 bit encoding for json and if it is possible to upload an image with json data in parrallel so I can benefit from the success responce without reloading pages. I would also like to avoid the plugins such as uploadify etc if possible. Also I'm uploading to folders/diectories listed in my html code, using checkboxes to hide and show elements and to identify the folder path for images.

**my jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    $('#add_photo_but').show();
    $('#photoChoose').show();   
    $('#addPhotoInstruction').hide();

});

    $(".add_photo_but").click(function()    {
        var file = $("image").files[0];
        var image = $("#addImage").val();


$.post("includes/add_photo.inc.php",{ checked_box : $('input:checkbox:checked').val(), image:image, imageFile:file},function(json)   {
    if(json.result === "success") {
        $(".addPhoto_result").html(json.message);

//$(".checkbox")[0].remove();
        $("input:checkbox:checked").parent().remove();
//  $('.add_intern').get(0).reset();
    }else{
        $(".addPhoto_result").html(json.message);
    }
});
        });//submit click
});//doc ready
</script>
```

**html form**

```
<div id="photos">

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="add_photo"  class="add_photo">
     <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){ ?>  

      <div class="photoAlbum_list">     

      <div id="#photoAlbumId" class="albumPhoto"><?php echo $row['album_name'];?></div>

      <img src="image/mandinga_folder.png" class="folder"/>

      <input type="checkbox" class="photoAlbumId" id="photoAlbumList" value="<?php echo $row['albumid'];?>"/>

      </div>

      <?php } ?>

    </form>

  <div id="addPhotoInstruction" style="display:block">Please choose an Album to Upload Photo's to</div>

  <div class="addPhoto_result"></div>

 <input id="photoChoose" type="file" multiple style="display:none"/>

<input type="button" id="add_photo_but" class="add_photo_but" name="add_photo_but" value="Add Photo" form="add_photo" style="display:none"/> 

  </div>
```